# remove page template from dropdown?

Tags: page-template

I created a page template, uploaded it, but then changed the template name later.

```
/*
Template Name: New Name
*/
```

Now, the new template name is showing up on the Page dropdown, but so is the old template name. How can I delete the old one from the list??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the old file from your theme's directory. That list of templates is generated from the files present in your theme, so you probably have two files.

Comment: yes, this was it, I'd deleted them locally but didn't delete them on the remote! thanks mr took :)